# Get certain values from complex table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet, vba

I have a rather complicated data structure in Excel ([Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzqw6D-H3UECc1NZRXBaVjhncEU/view?usp=sharing)). I would like to get certain values from this table:

[image]

I tried a combination of a row-column INDEX MATCH. However this did not work because I do not know how to locate the desired column.

Any suggestions how to transform this data structure?

Comment: A sample workbook would save us a lot of typing. I suspect a simple LOOKUP formula will work.

Comment: @Rory Please check my update!

Comment: Thanks. Can you name the ranges for each group?

Comment: I guess you mean this: `Group 2` goes from `A3:A14` and `Group 1` goes from `A15:A26`

Comment: No, I mean is it OK to assign names to the ranges for the formulas to use? Or are they always the same ranges?

Comment: Thx for your reply! The provided sheet is only a small part of my initial sheet. The sheet I took this sample from is around 10000 rows large, hence I would have to assign the named range to each of the 50 groups. Thx for your help!

Comment: Is it feasible to move the Date into a column next to the group and the Indicators? In that case you could reduce it to a simple SUMIFS

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Thx for your reply! Please outline your solution. I am happy to get every possible input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two helper columns in M and N.

In M4 enter:

```
=MATCH(H4,A:A,0)
```

IN N4 enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,H4)-1+M4
```

These will return the first and last row numbers for the Group.

Then in J4, array enter:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(INDEX($D:$D,$M4):INDEX($D:$D,$N4),MATCH(J$3,INDEX($D:$D,$M4):INDEX($D:$D,$N4),0)+1):INDEX($D:$D,$N4),MATCH(1,1/(INDEX(INDEX($B:$B,$M4):INDEX($B:$B,$N4),MATCH(J$3,INDEX($D:$D,$M4):INDEX($D:$D,$N4),0)+1):INDEX($B:$B,$N4)=$I4),0))
```

Remembering to confirm with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. Then fill across and down as needed.

There's probably a simpler version!

Answer (score 2):

If you can add a helper column A you can do the following
A3: `=E4`, A4: `=E4`, A5: `=E4`, A6: `=E4`, A7: `=E8`...

Once you have the first four values you can drag it down for the frist group and then from group 2 drag those four formulas down to the end.

You data will look like this:
[image]

Then in Cell K4 you enter the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS($E$3:$E$26,
        $A$3:$A$26, K$3,
        $B$3:$B$26, $I4,
        $C$3:$C$26, $J4)
```

Once you have this you can drag it down and right arbitrarily.

The only issue here is getting the Dates into the helper column, the approach above is only easy if all groups are of equal size but I assumed that given the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not required working *(helper)* cells, just a minor adjustment to your output table:

Enter the word `Date` in cell `I3`

Then enter this `FormulaArray` in cell `J4` then copy till `J7` then to range `K4:L7`

*(Formulas Array are entered by pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously)*

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$26,
MATCH($H4&$I$3&J$3,$A$2:$A$26&$B$2:$B$26&$D$2:$D$26,0)
+MATCH($I4,OFFSET($B$2:$B$26,
+MATCH($H4&$I$3&J$3,$A$2:$A$26&$B$2:$B$26&$D$2:$D$26,0),0),0))
```